# Xcode Objective C How to write in system's directory (Mac Os)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to write some txt file in /Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences folder:

```
NSString *FullPath = [@"/Library/Preferences" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"some_txt_file.txt"];
    NSString *str = @"some text";
    [str writeToFile:FullPath atomically:TRUE encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

But it is not working. If I change properties to "Read and Write" in this window, my code is working:

http://s52.radikal.ru/i135/1411/d0/32babf6a05a0.png

When I change this options, system ask me for a password!

How I can ask for a password and receive Administrator promts to write in this directory from my Cocoa application for Mac Os, when I click the button?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should reconsider whether you really need to write here and not `~/Library/Preferences` (in the user directory rather than root). Preferences are usually per-user things.

If you really do need to write in `/Library/Preferences` (root) then you will need elevated privleges. Apple provides a sample of this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html). Do note that unless I'm mistaken, your app will be rejected for this if are planning to put in on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think, it that, what I need! I will try to use it tomorrow, and now, I go to bed :)

Comment: Can i respect you? I haven't 15 reputation and i can't vote for you :(